# how to get a dbContext of applicationDbContext in a static method or in a class outside a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

when i work in a asp.net core class outside a controller, for example to get some records from my database-table tbl_Notes, then i need a _dbcontext or ApplicationDBContext to ask for data.

```
        public static async Task<User_SumModel> get_User_Sums(ClaimsPrincipal parUser)
    {
        //------------< get_User_Sums(User) >------------
        //*get User Summary Table
        //return null;

        if (parUser == null) return null;
        ApplicationDbContext _dbContext = Common.DB.get_DbContext();
        long sIDUser = await getIDUser_as_Number(parUser, _dbContext);
        User_SumModel summary = await _dbContext.tbl_User_Sums.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.IDUser == sIDUser);

        return summary;
        //------------</ get_User_Sums(User) >------------
    }
```

But how do i get a _dbContext in a public Task or shared class?

when i am in an partial view, then i want to add some data from the server.
[image]

the applicationdbcontext works well, but i cant get it ouside the controller in any public class
[image]

the method should be like this: get current dbcontext, open table, get data 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass `IServiceProvider` to the Class and create new scoped `ApplicationDbContext` from the `IServiceProvider`.
1.A simple code like below:

```
public class DataSeed
{       

    public static async Task InitializeData(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, bool createUsers = true)
    {
        using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var _context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

            //use _context as your requirement
        }
    }
}
```

2.Call the class

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {           
        //seed init data
        DataSeed.InitializeData(app.ApplicationServices).Wait();
    }
```

Comment: that's a great idea. 
i'm not shure if it gets pro problems running static _dbContent on multithreading asp.net.
So far, if it would create problems under _static , then i would be able to create it at runtime. thanks for that code. i will try it today.